# Got empty String when passing the "_id" from mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am creating a to-do list app,  using node js, express, and mongoose.

now I am trying the delete item function, using a checkbox from a form to pass the item._id to the express,

My data type for to-do list items is like this:

```
const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    context: String
});


todoList> db.todolists.find()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("65085d9277578bec0a1b9415"),
    context: 'angry',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("65085db177578bec0a1b9421"),
    context: 'extremely angry',
    __v: 0
  },
```

here is my EJS code:

```
<form class="delete-form" action="/delete" method="POST">
    <div class="todobox">
        <input name="checkbox" value="<%=item._id%>" type="checkbox" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <p>
            <%= item.context %>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here is my JS code:

```
app.post("/delete", async(req, res) => {
    const checkedItem = req.body.checkbox;
    console.log(checkedItem);
    todolist.deleteOne({_id: checkedItem})
    .then(console.log(`Item (${checkedItem}) was deleted.`)).catch((err) => {
         console.log(err);
     });
    items = await todolist.find({}, { _id: 0, context: 1 });
    console.log(`now the to-do-list has ${items.length} items.`)
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

I print out the item._id ( req.body.checkbox ). and only got an empty String "".
catch the error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "_id" for model "todolist"
    at ObjectId.cast (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:250:11)
    at SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1220:12)
    at SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1632:15)
    at cast (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:356:32)
    at Query.cast (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4911:12)
    at Query._castConditions (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2232:10)
    at model.Query._deleteOne (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3021:8)
    at model.Query.exec (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4430:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  stringValue: '""',
  messageFormat: undefined,
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '',
  path: '_id',
  reason: BSONError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer
      at new ObjectId (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/bson/lib/bson.cjs:2055:23)
      at castObjectId (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast/objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:248:12)
      at SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1220:12)
      at SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1632:15)
      at cast (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:356:32)
      at Query.cast (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4911:12)
      at Query._castConditions (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2232:10)
      at model.Query._deleteOne (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3021:8)
      at model.Query.exec (/Users/xuxiang/Documents/BACKEND/todoList-one/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4430:28),
  valueType: 'string',
  model: Model { todolist }
}
```

But when I pass item.context to express, it can successfully get the right result. for _id and __v, I can only got empty String "".

I also looked for the discussion of the course, asked ChatGPT,  didn't get a solution.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You have no `_id` on your item as you projected it out: `.find({}, { _id: 0, context: 1 });`. If you want the `_id` returned, use: `.find({}, { _id: 1, context: 1 });`

Comment: nimrod serok: 
Sir, Thank you so much, I changed to .find({}, { _id: 1, context: 1 }); in my delete METHOD, now I can get the _id. 

In my Method:
app.post("/delete", async(req, res) => {
    ...
    items = await todolist.find({}, { _id: 0, context: 1 });
    ...
}); 

is not related to the delete function, just for refreshing the item list for express, But when it was added, still affected my "req.body", is it because it's an async? 
Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Main issue is checkedItem data type is String and while use in query it must be ObjectId

```
  // import 
    const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')

app.post("/delete", async (req, res) => {
    const checkedItem = req.body.checkbox;
    // check checkedItem is valid objectID or not
    if (!ObjectID.isvalid(checkedItem)) 
        res.status(400).send({ code: 400, success: false, error: 'invalid id' })
    console.log(checkedItem);
    todolist.deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectID(checkedItem) })
        .then(console.log(`Item (${checkedItem}) was deleted.`)).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    const items = await todolist.find({}, { _id: 1, context: 1 });
    console.log(`now the to-do-list has ${items.length} items.`)
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

other method with trycatch error handle

```
  // import 
    const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')

    app.post("/delete", async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const checkedItem = req.body.checkbox;
            // check checkedItem is valid objectID or not
            if (!ObjectID.isvalid(checkedItem)) throw new Error('invalid id')
            console.log(checkedItem);
            todolist.deleteOne({ _id: new ObjectID(checkedItem) })
                .then(console.log(`Item (${checkedItem}) was deleted.`)).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            const items = await todolist.find({}, { _id: 1, context: 1 });
            console.log(`now the to-do-list has ${items.length} items.`)
            res.redirect("/");
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send({ code: 400, success: false, error: error.message })
            // or
            res.redirect("/400");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @nimrod serok. I changed my delete METHOD From

```js
app.post("/delete", async(req, res) => {
    ...
    items = await todolist.find({}, { _id: 0, context: 1 });
    ...
});
```

To:

```js
app.post("/delete", async(req, res) => {
    ...
    items = await todolist.find({}, { _id: 1, context: 1 });
    ...
});
```

This affected the `req.body`, and I can get the _id now.
However I am still confused about why it will cause this issue.

If anyone has an idea please kindly share,
Thank @nimrod serok, and thank you very much.